# Spacing in pgfplots bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, pgfplots

I've been trying to plot an xbar graph using pgfplots within a tikzpicture. I *want* to be able to only show the yaxis on the left and the x axis on the bottom. When I set `axis y line=left` and `axis x line=bottom` though, I get arrows on the axis. Is it possible to remove them? Also, I can't seem to control the spacing of the bar plots, is that possible? I'd like them to be much closer together then they are currently. Here's my attempt so far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xbar,
    symbolic y coords={4 Sep 11,4 Oct 11,4 Nov 11},
    width=0.4\textwidth,
    height=0.15\textheight,
    nodes near coords={\$\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
    nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    xtick=\empty,
    axis x line=bottom,
    axis y line=left,
    xmin=0,
    bar width=12pt,
    enlarge limits=0.2,
  ]
  \addplot[fill=blue]
    coordinates {(121.28,4 Nov 11) (100.00,4 Oct 11) (50.00,4 Sep 11)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The output of which is:

[image]

Things I have tried: `enlarge limits` (If I enable it, the plot looks a bit nicer), `xbar interval` and shrinking the height of the plot to no avail. I'm a little stumped at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the starred version of these options. Regarding the distance between the bars you should increase the height of the plot.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
      xbar,
      symbolic y coords={4 Sep 11,4 Oct 11,4 Nov 11},
      width=0.4\textwidth,
      height=0.25\textheight,
      nodes near coords={\$\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
      nodes near coords align={horizontal},
      xtick=\empty,
      axis x line*=bottom,
      axis y line*=left,
      xmin=0,
      bar width=12pt,
      enlargelimits=0.2,
    ]
      \addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {(121.28,4 Nov 11) (100.00,4 Oct 11) (50.00,4 Sep 11)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Details in the [pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) manual

Comment: Oh boy, that was awesome -- everything's working! The starred versions got rid of the arrows. `enlargelimits=0.2` caused the x limits to change also so I used `enlarge y limits=0.2` and that did the job perfectly. As for the spacing, it seems to be much better. Thanks!

Comment: @slurms: I would recommend you set `enlarge x limits={upper, value=0.2}`. That way, only the upper limit is moved, so the bars still start at the y axis.